# Does a pointer to const have the same effect as __restrict?

Tags: c, constants, restrict-qualifier

When we have constant data, e.g. in the form

- `double const * const` or
- `double const *`

does this give the compiler the same information as `__restrict` / does it have the same effect?

As far as I understand, `__restrict` basically promises, that the data pointed to will not be altered by/through another pointer. So, a pointer to a const value makes kind of the same promise, doesn't it?

`__restrict` here refers to the keyword in Visual Studio. I guess the meaning is similar in GCC.

Comment: `__restrict`, beginning with two underscores, is, by convenion an architecture dependent feature and must be used carefully if at all.  You are discouraged as a programmer to use it as it has that prefix to indicate it has been used in the implementation of some compiler/language/implementation feature and must not be used by client software.  On the other side, `const` is a standard language feature that allows the compiler to detect tries to change the value of a constant and warn the user of value misuse.

Answer (score 5):

No, `__restrict` means that the pointer in question is the only pointer in the current scope that points at that particular piece of data, i.e. that the pointer is not *aliased*. This is not the same as being `const`, although I guess that it's more interesting for modifiable data.

Comment: `restrict` is still interesting for pointers to `const` when it's used in conjunction with other restricted pointers to non-const, e.g. in `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to `const` doesn't tell the compiler anything, it requests warnings for some implicit conversions. Only if an object itself is declared `const` the compiler may assume it stays unchanged (even if `const` is cast away).

`__restrict`, on the other hand, *is* a promise to the compiler, namely that the referenced object isn't aliased by another pointer in the current scope.

I couldn't find `__restrict` in the GCC documentation, but `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` accepts `int *__restrict foo;` and `int *restrict foo;` as compatible declarations, indicating they have the same semantics; implying it isn't the same as [MSVC's `__restrict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ft82fed.aspx).

For C99 `restrict` (but not MSVC `__restrict`), as I read the standard, a `restrict`-qualified pointer to `const`-qualified type does promise the referenced object doesn't change (if the pointer is used to access the object), cf. C11 (n1570) 6.7.3.1 p4.